# what is the probability that part is actually defective?

Tags: probability

I've this "simple" yes it's simple, question, from which I got different outcomes, and I would like to have a differente opinion.

A manufacturing process has a 3% defect rate. Inspectors catch 95% of defects but also fail 5% of non-defective parts. If we pick a part at random from all those that pass inspection, what is the probability that part is actually defective?

On my side , I get 0,5% of probability that part is defective if picked randomly.

In the other hand, 0,16% seems to be the write answer.

If someone could share his result, It would be very much appreciated.

Rgds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be tackled using conditional probability.

We are seeking the probability that a part is defective, given that it has passed inspection. $Pr(\text{defective}|\text{passed inspection})$.

By Bayes’ theorem, this is equal to $$\frac{Pr(\text{passed inspection}|\text{defective})Pr(\text{defective})}{Pr(\text{passed inspection})}$$

We are given that $Pr(\text{defective}) = 0.03$ and we know that $Pr(\text{passed inspection}|\text{defective}) = 1 - 0.95 = 0.05$ because this is the probability that a defective item is *not* detected.

We can then calculate $Pr(\text{passed inspection})$ as

$$Pr(\text{passed inspection}|\text{defective})Pr(\text{defective}) + Pr(\text{passed inspection}|\text{not defective})Pr(\text{not defective})$$

(because there are two ways of passing inspection, one if the item is defective, and another if the item is not defective)

which is

$$0.05 \times 0.03 + (1-0.05) \times (1 -0.03) = 0.923$$

So for $Pr(\text{defective}|\text{passed inspection})$ we have $\frac{0.03 \times 0.05}{0.923} \approx 0.0016 = 0.16\%$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. Best.

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho No problem! If my answer was helpful, marking it as accepted would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'll do that, I'll mark as accepted. 
Nevertheless, I still have something around my mind about this.

If we're given :

Defect rate 0,03 mean 0,07 of non defect right?
We can put this way:

O,03 defect

0,07 Non Defect

When inspector catch 95% of defect  we can put that this way

```
0,03  Defect    
**** O,05 Fail Inspect
**** 0,95 Succeed Inspec
```

while 
0,07 still non Defect right?

Still, 5% of Non-Defective are not Catch so we can represent like this

```
0,03  Defect    
**** O,05 Fail Inspect
**** 0,95 Succeed Inspect
0,07 Non Defect
**** 0,05 Fail inspect
**** 0,95 Succeed Inspect
```

So, the total probability of parts with defects if random select is = (0,05)x(0,03) + (0,05)x(0,07) = 0,15 + 0,35 = 0,50

Now if I divide 0,5 by 0,03 (which is the percentage of defects parts) I get 0,16%
exactly the same value as yours, but this 0,16% in my interpretation is the  proportion of defective parts given Defectives. In other words, is the probability of pick a part selected random from the Defect only, and not from all inspects.

I know, the odds are against me.

Thanks in advance for you feedback

Comment: you are misusing the percentages: $3\%=0.03; 5\%=0.05$.

Comment: Indeed, I mess up with numbers. I've done necessary corrections